# How do i save a File from a jfilechooser into the project folder?

Tags: java, swing

I just finished uploading a image in java and now I want to upload files like docx, pdf etc.

I tried to use/change the code I used for uploading image but without any succéss.

```
private void btnOpenFileActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    int returnValue = openFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    if(returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        try{
            openFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            lblMessage.setText("File Succesfully loaded");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            lblMessage.setText("Failed to load File");
        }
    }
    else{
        lblMessage.setText("No file Choosen");
    }
}
```

This is how I choose the file and I dont have any code for uploading/saving it in the project folder

Comment: So, what is the problem? Do get an error when selecting a docx or pdf file?

Comment: No, I can select the file/filetype but I don't have the code to upload it I've tried to write some without success, I've tried some paths to move a file from one absolute path to another but I'm not sure this is the way to go..

Comment: If you know how to upload an image file, upload of other file types is just the same.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you asign your chosen file to a variable like so:

```
File theSelectedFile = openFileChooser.getSelectedFile();
```

Then becouse you only need a copy of the file you can just use a simple file copy operation by adding this to the line below:

```
String placeToSaveFile = "C:/path/to/your/project/";
Files.copy(theSelectedFile.toPath(), new File(placeToSaveFile).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Comment: `Files.copy(theSelectedFile.toPath(), new File(placeToSaveFile).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);` ** Files.copy() does not accept String argument. Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: @GeorgeZougianos Thanks I have fixed it.